# Second a day video "counter"

Tags: video-editor, vegas-pro

I'm trying to edit my 1 Second a day type of video and I'm unsure how to put a date below which increases every second?

The text would look something like this: "April 6 2016", 
then after a second it would change to: "April 7 2016".

Any idea how I could do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sony Vegas you can use [Text Wizard](http://vegasaur.com/text-generation-wizard) from Vegasaur Toolkit. It can easily create various counters. Vegasaur has free 30-day trial, so just install it and go to menu *View > Extensions > Vegasaur > Timeline > Text Generation Wizard*.
Please note that the appearance of the text (font, color, size, etc.) is determined by the selected preset.